# Declaring a generic iterator

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I have the following problem: I need to make a function which takes two iterators and a value and checks if the value is found between the two. The catch: I can only have one template parameter which denotes the type of the elements from the iterators and the value.

My try is like this, but doesn't seem to work:

```
template <typename T>
T myFind(iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag,T> begin, iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, T> end, T elem){
// Code
}
```

But this doesn't work then:

```
// vector<int> vect; list<string> lst;
myFind(vect.begin(), vect.end(), 15);
myFind(lst.begin(), lst.end(), "some element");
```

Any ideas?
Code after changes:

```
 template <typename T> 
 T myFind(T begin, T end,typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type elem){
   for(T it = begin; it != end; ++it){
     if(*it == elem){
       return it;
     }
    }
    return end;
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using a bidirectional iterator?

Comment: It was part of my last try to make this work :)

Comment: "I can only have one template parameter" -- why? That's a completely stupid restriction.

Comment: @Xeo But unfortunately it is a restriction I have to keep to. I know how to solve the issue with two template parameters..but not with one.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You've written an elaborate, restricted version of `std::find`. Why isn't `std::find` appropriate?

Comment: `std::iterator`, despite its name, is not an iterator type. It provides a handful of `typedef` names, nothing more. That's why the first solution doesn't work.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you for for clearing things out. The requirements have been to implement such a find..for me std::find is good enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you have one template parameter that is the iterator type? If so:

```
template <typename It>
typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type
myFind(It begin, It end, typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type elem){
  // ...
}
```

Otherwise, I think your restriction is too strong.

After your edit: If you want to do `-` on the iterator that is returned (as you show you do in the comments), you need a random access iterator. However, `std::list::iterator` is a bidirectional iterator so you can't. You will need to use [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) (or in C++03, use [std::advance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)).

Comment: This could be it..I'll give it a try in a moment and come back with a feedback :)

Comment: This is what I was searching for, but it doesn't seem to work for list. I am trying "myFind(lst.begin(), lst.end(), "SOME sTRING") - lst.begin());" but it sais "no match for operator- in...

Comment: @Daniel `myFind` returns a `std::string` in this case and you're trying to do `- lst.begin()` on it. Do you want your `myFind` to return an `It` instead?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention that. I changed the return type to T. Let me post in my question the changed code now.

Comment: Added the code to the question. Basically I am trying to find if an element is in the range of iterators given. If so, return first occurrence.

Comment: That answered a lot of my questions. Thanks!